# Operand of * must be a pointer

Tags: c

This is my script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14;

int main(void){
    double hasil, input;
    printf("Enter a positive number : ");
    scanf("%lf",&input);
    hasil = PI * input;
    printf("\nThe result is : %lf",hasil);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get error * must be a pointer? What's it? I mean '*' sign is to multiply number....

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your PI constant contains a semicolon which will terminate the expression prematurely;

```
#define PI 3.14;
```

...will result in the expression;

```
hasil = 3.14; * input;
```

It should be defined as only;

```
#define PI 3.14
```

Comment: oh jeez, one of those things you know but you miss to notice after editing since you replaced consts

Comment: oof thanks, this saved me from a real head scratcher

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` from your `#define`, it should be `#define PI 3.14`

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
#define PI 3.14;
```

should be

```
#define PI 3.14
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because  of error in macro

```
#define PI 3.14;
```

should be written as

```
#define PI 3.14
```

Because the macro has been written this way it gives you an error when processor substitutes this in place of each `PI` occurence.

Answer (score 0):

change the line to,

```
hasil = input * PI;
```